# Why pair numbers using bit interleaving instead of separating by high and low bits?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I recently learned of [Morton coding (Z-order curve)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) as a bitwise pairing function.  It was presented to me as a computationally faster way to pair numbers compared to the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

The way Morton coding works is to combine two numbers by interleaving their bits and storing the result in a wider data type.  For example, interleave the bits of two 8-bit integers and store the result as a 16-bit integer.

Why would you want to interleave the bits instead of splitting the two numbers among the high and low bits of the target data type?  I would expect using high and low bits to be faster still.  When might there be an advantage in interleaving them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the Cantor pairing function, and unlike concatenation, it does not place an a-priori bound on the coordinates. In order words, Morton-coding can also be formulated for arbitrary length integers. That is not the case for concatenation really, because while anything can be concatenated, the result would be ambiguous and its interpretation would depend on the original sizes of the coordinates. The sizes of all but one dimension have to be fixed to avoid ambiguity.

If it is used in a context where there is an a-priori bound anyway, and locality is not an issue, then of course concatenation is an even simpler option.

Locality is a commonly used advantage though. Two coordinates that are close by are mostly mapped relatively close by in terms of their Z-values as well. The Hilbert curve works even better for that purpose, but is harder to encode, decode, and offset (and like concatenation, it also depends on the size of the space which must be fixed in advance). Concatenated coordinates preserve locality in only one dimension (but really well) and not the other(s), but are the easiest to encode/decode/offset (when these things are possible at all, which means the size of all but one dimension must be predetermined).